# Select tow row where before and after specific create date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an table with create date column. Is there anyway to select exact tow rows that have create date before and after specified date in one select statement without inner query and join?

```
Id - date
1 - 1/1/2013
2 - 2/1/2013
3 - 6/1/2013
4 - 9/2/2014
```

For 4/1/2013 result is:

```
2 - 2/1/2013
3 - 6/1/2013
```

Comment: at least show some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: what are tow rows?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Don't use images of data, the previous text was much better as we can use that directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sign(date - date '2013-04-01')
                                order by abs(date - date '2013-04-01') as seqnum
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This could return three rows -- if a date exactly matches.  I view this as a feature, because you don't specify what to do in that case.

In Oracle 12C, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by sign(date - date '2013-04-01')
                            order by abs(date - date '2013-04-01')
                           )
fetch first 2 rows only;
```

Note:  If one of the dates matches the incoming date, the results are indeterminate (among the three possible dates).